# Onclick listener not responding to clicks on imageview

Tags: java, android, onclick, imageview, manifest

I have a problem on getting my imageview button to work onclick. what im trying to do is to make the first image invisible  so that the second one behind it can appear and at the same time define int special based on what image that has been clicked.

```
    public class TrainingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static int special;
    public static ImageView a12,b13,a12a,b13a;
  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_page);
        a12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.young);
        b13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.old);
        a12a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.young2);
        b13a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.old2);
        a12.setOnClickListener(this);
        b13.setOnClickListener(this);
        a12a.setOnClickListener(this);
        b13a.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.young) {
            a12.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            a12a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            special =0;
        } else {
            a12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            a12a.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.old) {
            b13.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            b13a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            special =1;
        } else {
            b13.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b13a.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

this is my main class file. I've had already tried this codes in a new project and it works there but somehow doesn't here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/gray_color"
    tools:context="com.codestudioapps.cardioexcercise.WalkandStep.activities.TrainingActivity">

  
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/young2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/img_body_surface_area1"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/young"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/img_body_surface_area" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/old2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/img_body_fat1"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/old"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/img_body_fat" />

</FrameLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the layout. The problem might happen because of my manifest file but im unsure. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your question is vague, the last speed is ambiguous try to explain it more.

Comment: did you try to compare the views with the "v" paramether, instead of comparing their ids

Comment: The problem is that you are casting ImageButton to ImageView. Change the following line of code:

public static ImageButton a12,b13,a12a,b13a;

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems okay. Just, casting problem i.e. ImageButton to ImageView.
Your code should be as follows:

```
public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
     public static int special;
     public static ImageButton a12, b13, a12a, b13a;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

    a12 = findViewById(R.id.young);
    b13 = findViewById(R.id.old);
    a12a = findViewById(R.id.young2);
    b13a = findViewById(R.id.old2);
    a12.setOnClickListener(this);
    b13.setOnClickListener(this);
    a12a.setOnClickListener(this);
    b13a.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.young) {
        a12.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        a12a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        special = 0;
    } else {
        a12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        a12a.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (v.getId() == R.id.old) {
        b13.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        b13a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        special = 1;
    } else {
        b13.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b13a.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }
}
```